# SSD 3.0 slowing Bios boot and Windows?

Tags: hard-drive, boot, usb, ssd

I have SSD with 3.0 connection connected to USB 3.0 Port on my Laptop PC. There was no problem until yesterday when suddenly my PC decided to do something strange.

It is connected with SATA to USB 3.0 (SS) cable to 3.0 USB port

When I connect SSD to port and boot system booting screen took around 2 mins, also windows booting takes long and I'm not able to start applications like MiniTool Partition Wizard until SSD is mounted by windows and automatic opened the disk folder. When I double click to open it just not doing anything.

I tried to connect the disk to another PC and there was no problem with the SSD. I also tried to connect to another USB port - no change.
I also tried to reinstall USB drivers, also no change.
Btw. something like USB 2.0 stick is working fine.

Comment: Just to make sure: You are referring to _USB_ 3.0, right? Because there’s also _SATA_ 3.0 and “SSD 3.0” isn’t a thing.

Comment: Please delete the comment.  This is the sort of thing you add to your question and not in a comment.  I added it for you.